# Unity3D - Create a NGUI Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I'm working on some project where I need to create on the fly, buttons with NGUI.
I found some answers but none of them could help me. Iknow it's simple but according to what I found
on http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=81.0
and in NGUI script (UICreateWidgetWizard.cs), like:

```
            UILabel lbl = NGUITools.AddWidget<UILabel>(go);
```

it's still not working..

An my code is the following:

```
            UIButton button =  NGUITools.AddWidget<UIButton>(parent);
```

Thanks for yout help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either as @pfranza suggests, create a prefab of your UIButtons that you can reference as a public object in your script, then to create it use the

```
GameObject newButton = NGUITools.AddChild(mParentGameObject, mButtonPrefab);
```

Alternatively, you can fully create it at runtime if you wish:

```
    UISprite mButtonSprite = NGUITools.AddSprite(mParentGameObject, mAtlas, "Button");
    //Button is the name of the sprite in the atlas

    mButtonSprite.MakePixelPerfect();
    NGUITools.AddWidgetCollider(mButtonSprite.gameObject);
    mButtonSprite.gameObject.AddComponent<UIButton>();
    //add any further components/set up you like.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a prefab out of a button that you want to use as a template;  Attach that prefab to your script as a GameObject.  Then in your script you can clone that object and activate it.